# Getting to 16 Available Bits in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I recently came across a YouTube video that discussed handling GPS coordinates by using space filled curves. There was a formula provided to accomplish this so I've decided to try and replicate it, however I have not been able to figure out how to get to the same result using JavaScript.

**The formula was as follows:**

> Scale Latitude and longitude to use 16 available bits each:

```
scaled_x = (-122.4012 + 180) / 360 * 2 ^ 16   // result = 10485
scale_y = (37.7839 + 90) / 180 * 2 ^ 16       // result = 46524
```

[Video Reference](https://youtu.be/KaRbKdMInuc?t=2807)

---

I've tries several ways of writing the formula and my results are far off from what I should be getting based on what was shown in the presentation. Either the presentation was inaccurate or I've not landed on the correct way of getting to this.

Here are some of my attempts, all fail.

*Using Pow*

```
base = Math.round((lat + 180) / 360);
scale = Math.pow(base * 2, 16); // Result = 0
```

*Exact Formula*

```
base = Math.round((lat + 180) / 360 * 2 ^ 16); // Result = 16
```

*Inline Power*

```
base = Math.round((lat + 180) / 360 * Math.pow(2, 16)); // Result = -22282
```

Does anyone know how this formula needs to be structured in JavaScript to get the expected outcome?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  You're trying to bitmask 16 bits?  `val && 0xFF`?

Comment: @Amy This partially what is unclear to me as well. You can take a look at the video here https://youtu.be/KaRbKdMInuc?t=2807

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
base = Math.round((lat + 180) / 360);
scale = Math.pow(base * 2, 16)
```

This doesn't work because you're rounding the value before multiplying it by 2<sup>16</sup> -- so it will round to either 0 or 1. This is not what you want.

```
base = Math.round((lat + 180) / 360 * 2 ^ 16);
```

In Javascript -- and many other languages -- `^` is used for bitwise XOR, not exponentiation. `2 ^ 16` is 18, not 65536.

```
base = Math.round((lat + 180) / 360 * Math.pow(2, 16));
```

This looks correct. The result you've quoted isn't right for `lat = -122.4012`, though -- did you leave out the `+ 180`, perhaps?

Comment: You are correct, the last formula was the correct the correct on. The problem was coming from the coordinate being passes was a string. By adding parseFloat(lat) the problem landed correctly. Your comment about -122.4012 returning the correct result for you made me look deeper into it. Also, changing from `Math.round()` to `Math.floor()` solved the problem of then being off by 1. `Math.floor((parseFloat(lat) + 180) / 360 * Math.pow(2, 16));` <- Solution